# How do I insert text if a div exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

First off, I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm working on wordpress plugins so a huge apology if this seems a little vague... (I have decent knowledge of HTML/CSS so I'm getting there!)

I need to display the text "Starting" to appear before the date in "tribe-event-date-start" **ONLY IF** the class "tribe-event-date-end" exists.

For example:

```
<span class="tribe-event-date-start">3 June - 9:00 pm</span> - <span class="tribe-event-date-end">6 June - 9:00 pm</span>
```

I've done this already in HTML by editing the CSS like this:

```
.tribe-event-date-start:before {
    content: "Starting ";
}
```

...but this puts the text in front of **ALL** dates which isn't ideal...

Is this something I can do in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I have code both scenarios if class exits or not, I hope it will solve your issue.

```js
    if($('.tribe-event-date-end').length > 0){
      $('.tribe-event-date-start').addClass('start');
    }

if($('.tribe-event-date-end2').length > 0){
      $('.tribe-event-date-start2').addClass('start');
    }
```

```css
.tribe-event-date-start.start:before,
.tribe-event-date-start2.start:before {
        content: "Starting ";
    }
    
    .wrap {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="wrap">
    <label>If <strong>tribe-event-date-end</strong> class exists.</label></br>
    <span class="tribe-event-date-start">3 June - 9:00 pm</span> - <span class="tribe-event-date-end">6 June - 9:00 pm</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wrap">
    <label>If <strong>tribe-event-date-end2</strong> class not exists.</label></br>
    <span class="tribe-event-date-start2">3 June - 9:00 pm</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However, I'm struggling to discover where I would actually put this code as there are many .php files in the Wordpress files...
 (I'll keep at it!) Thanks again. :)

Comment: Add script code in header.php file and css in style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// select element with class 'tribe-event-date-end' immediately preceded by an element with class 'tribe-event-date-start'
$('.tribe-event-date-start+.tribe-event-date-end')
    // traverse to the left sibling of the matched element with class 'tribe-event-date-start'
    .prev('.tribe-event-date-start')
    // add a class to the sibling element that triggers the css selector below
    .addClass('show-starting');
```

```css
.tribe-event-date-start.show-starting:before {
    content: "Starting ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<strong>With tribe-event-date-end sibling - will have "Starting" prepended</strong><br>
<span class="tribe-event-date-start">3 June - 9:00 pm</span> - <span class="tribe-event-date-end">6 June - 9:00 pm</span><br>
<br>
<strong>Without tribe-event-date-end sibling - won't have "Starting" prepended</strong><br>
<span class="tribe-event-date-start">3 June - 9:00 pm</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However, I'm struggling to discover where I would actually put this code as there are many .php files in the Wordpress files...
 (I'll keep at it!) Thanks again. :)